# Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "is_granted" does not exist

Tags: twig, silex

I'm using Silex and can't use the is_granted function in a template.  I can't find anything in the docs about why this isn't working.  Any hints?

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../templates',
    'twig.options' => array('cache' => __DIR__.'/../cache'),
));

$app['debug'] = true;

$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'login' => array(
                'pattern' => '^/login$',
        ),
        'secured' => array(
                'pattern' => '^.*$',
                'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
                'users' => array(
                        'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
                ),
        ),
);

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig');
});

$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
            'error'                 => $app['security.last_error']($request),
            //'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to add the symfony/bridge components as well:

Add this to composer.json and update.

```
"symfony/twig-bridge": "2.1.*",
```

And hey... it'll work like expected.

Comment: And although I can't find it, supposedly this should be the way you add Twig to Silex.  twig-bridge will automatically include twig/twig.

Answer (score 4):

I had to use this workaround (don't know yet if any drawbacks)

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('is_granted', function($role) use ($app){
    return $app['security']->isGranted($role);
});
$app['twig']->addFunction($function);
```

Comment: Naabys, did you find any other solution rather than using this?

Comment: Well, not yet, but i'm actually working on another Silex project where I'll try a different way of doing this. I'll keep you updated

Comment: I ended up using yours but set up my application differently - if you're interested, here's a [link](https://github.com/J7mbo/silex-auth-skeleton) for my current architecture.

Comment: it seems to be good work. And you used my favorite license! ;)

Forked.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface`we must provide the second parameter which rights we are trying to assess. The second parameter will be sent to the voter (eg. a user)

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('is_granted', function($role, 
$object = null) use ($app){
    return $app['security']->isGranted($role, $object);
});
$app['twig']->addFunction($function);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is most likely caused by the order of registering classes. Order should be SecurityServiceProvider then boot your application then the TwigServiceProvider registration. TwigServiceProvider checks for $app['security'] to setup Twig SecurityExtension. So order matters

```
// Security service
$app["security.firewalls"] = array();
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());

// Boot your application to call SecurityServiceProvider()->boot()
$app->boot();

// Twig service
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
  'twig.path' => sprintf("%s/../views", __DIR__),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Symfony 2.6 components it becomes **security.authorization_checker** instead of **security**, as in:

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('is_granted', function($role,$object = null) use ($app){
    return $app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted($role,$object);
});
$app['twig']->addFunction($function);
```